# NGINX is reading files with Apache permission, is it wrong?

Tags: centos, security, apache-httpd, webserver, nginx

I have a server - S1 - using Apache as its webserver, and another server -S2 - running NGINX as its webserver. S2 is mounted in S1 and S1 is uploading files to S2 using NFS.

So newly added files in the NGINX Server, S2, has owner and group of Apache. I've had no problem with serving files, everything is working fine, but is it a security issue that I'm reading Apache files using NGINX? Is it wrong at all? If yes so, what choices do I have??

---

**UPDATE 1 :** The user set for NGINX in the configuration file is nginx, not apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every access (read/write) to a file on NFS server, the client shares the user id and group id of the user to the NFS server. Only if the NFS server confirms that the user id and group id indeed can access the file, it permits the request to pass through.

For your question of:

> So newly added files in the NGINX Server, S2, has owner and group of
>   Apache. I've had no problem with serving files, everything is working
>   fine, but is it a security issue that I'm reading Apache files using
>   NGINX? Is it wrong at all? If yes so, what choices do I have??

*How* in the first place, NGINX is able to access files created by Apache? Here, I assume that the Apache process in S1 is creating the files. And the created files are world readable(?). If it is, that could be a security question, depending upon your context. Typically the files that Apache process creates are world readable, unless the script that initiated the creation of file, has also code to change the permissions explicitly. You may want to take a look at it.

There could be that the `user id` and `group id` of Apache on S1, matches that of `user id` and `group id` of NGINX on S2. Or if that is not the case, then the directories that contain these files are world readable with `read and executable bits turned on` (one more security concern), so that other than Apache (on S1), anyone can access these directories.

If NGINX and Apache are running with privileged ports, you may want to be extremely careful. Any identified privilege escalation or root exploit vulnerabilities of your running versions of NGINX/Apache could allow a hacker to gain access to your server. If one of NGINX/Apache is holding very sensitive data, you are providing a way to get to that via the other server.

While the external world might not know that, NGINX process is sharing the same folders as Apache, anyone having local shell access to S1 or S2 can eventually make use of vulnerabilities to gain access to the other server.

If there is no other option than to share the files across servers/processes, you may want to look into these:
- file read and write permissions
- folder access permissions

If the shared files are source files, it is advised that, they are part of version control repository (like GIT) and latest code is checked out at both the locations (which eventually means that you are maintaining two copies).

If your use case is known, better alternatives can come from others around.